# Unexpected Behaviour of PasswordResetView which sends too many consecutive emails

Tags: django, email, view

My Django 3.0 Project is using the default Django Reset Password view, so in my url.py:

```
path('password_reset', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset')
```

There is a strange behaviour because when I request reseting the password, the view sends a lot of emails to the email address I introduced (let´s say 37 emails). This happened regardless using SendGrid or AWS SES, so something wrong is happening in the view.

I investigated and I think the problem is in the [PasswordResetForm class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/aff7a58aef0264e5b2740e5df07894ecc0d7a580/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L251) which the view uses to send emails. Such form has a `get_users()` method, which return matching user(s) who should receive a reset, it retrieves all the active users who provided the email.

```
def get_users(self, email):
        """Given an email, return matching user(s) who should receive a reset.
        This allows subclasses to more easily customize the default policies
        that prevent inactive users and users with unusable passwords from
        resetting their password.
        """
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()
        active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(**{
            '%s__iexact' % email_field_name: email,
            'is_active': True,
        })
        return (
            u for u in active_users
            if u.has_usable_password() and
            _unicode_ci_compare(email, getattr(u, email_field_name))
        )
```

The `save()` method of the form sends an email to each of the users returned by `get_users()`. I think my problem is that I registered several users (let´s say 37) with the same email (as Django allows this by default), and now the save method is sending one email message for each of these users to the email address.

```
def save(self, domain_override=None,
             subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
             email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
             from_email=None, request=None, html_email_template_name=None,
             extra_email_context=None):
        """
        Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and send it to the
        user.
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()
        for user in self.get_users(email):
            user_email = getattr(user, email_field_name)
            context = {
                'email': user_email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
                **(extra_email_context or {}),
            }
            self.send_mail(
                subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, from_email,
                user_email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
            )
```

My question: is it really a desirable default behaviour of Django? and how could it be fixed to send only one email when reseting the password, regardless of how many users are registered with the same email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be quite simply customised. As you have observed, the problem you have is that `PasswordResetForm` sends an email to all of the users. So we can simply subclass that form, and adjust the `get_users` method. Something like this:

```
class MyPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def get_users(self, email):
        # do what the form did before
        users = super().get_users(email)
        # choose the first user
        try:
             user = next(users)
             return [user]
        except StopIteration:  # Incase there are no users
             return []
```

Then we will need to use the new form in our `PasswordResetView`:

```
class MyPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    form_class = MyPasswordResetForm
```

Then you need to use your `MyPasswordResetView` in `urls.py` where you had previously used `PasswordResetView`.

With regards to why the default behaviour is to return all Users, the docstring sheds some light here:

> This allows subclasses to more easily customize the default policies that prevent inactive users and users with unusable passwords from resetting their password.